# Apple Maps URL Schema for multi stops

Tags: ios, swift, url-scheme, apple-maps

Apple had introduced the add stops for Apple maps. And I try to have a turn by turn navigation from my app to apple maps with multi-stops feature. Do they introduce their new URL schema to show direction? Or someone knows how can I handle with this new feature from Apple?

I've read this document but it seems they don't update this document for new features.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MapLinks/MapLinks.html